# Creating bokeh data_table on pandas dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, bokeh

The example code I am pasting is taken from the following link.

[layout for multiple Data Table as children in each Bokeh Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693284/layout-for-multiple-data-table-as-children-in-each-bokeh-tab)

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs, TableColumn,DataTable, Div
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, layout
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, Spacer 

output_notebook()

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="A", title="A"),
        TableColumn(field="B", title="B"),
        TableColumn(field="C", title="C"),
        TableColumn(field="D", title="D"),]


data1 = {"A":np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "B": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "C": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "D": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10)}
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data1)
p1 = DataTable(source=source1, columns=columns, width=300, height=200,editable=True)


data2 = {"A":np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "B": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "C": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "D": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10)}
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data2)      
p2 = DataTable(source=source2, columns=columns, width=300, height=200,editable=True)



data3 = {"A":np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "B": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "C": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10), 
        "D": np.random.randint(23, 89, 10)}
source3 = ColumnDataSource(data3)       
p3 = DataTable(source=source3, columns=columns, width=300, height=200,editable=True)


dumbdiv = Div()
l1 = layout([[p1], [p2], [p3]], sizing_mode='fixed')


tab1 = Panel(child=l1, title="Three Tables")
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1],sizing_mode='scale_width')
show(tabs)
```

It works perfectly fine. My question is, if I have 100(or even more) dataframes then is there an easy way (for loop perhaps) of creating layouts accordingly? In other words, the number of dataframes I have in a list can vary and I would like to know if the bokeh layout can be arranged accordingly. Something like:-

```
layout_list=[]
for i in range(len(df_list)):
    source = ColumnDataSource(df_list[i])
    p1 = DataTable(source=source1, columns=columns, width=300, height=200,editable=True)
    layout_list.append(p1)
tab1 = Panel(child=layout_list, title="Three Tables")
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1],sizing_mode='scale_width')
show(tabs)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to other posts of @bigreddot, I figured it out.

mdf is a list of dataframes.

```
output_file("layout.html")
plots = []
for i in range(len(mdf)):
    print(i)
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(mdf[i])    
    Columns = [TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in mdf[i].columns]
    p1 = DataTable(source=source1,columns=Columns, width=3000, height=200,editable=True)
    plots.append(p1)

show(column(*plots))
```